# Theorem 3.22 in Baby Rudin: Is this proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Here's Theorem 3.22 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, third edition.

> $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $$\left\vert \sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right\vert \leq  \varepsilon $$ if $m \geq n \geq N$.

My proof:

> Let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. If $\sum a_n$ converges, then the sequence $\{s_n \}$ is Cauchy, so, given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find an integer $N$ such that $$\left\vert s_m - s_n \right\vert < \varepsilon$$ if $m \geq N$, $n \geq N$. So if $m \geq n \geq N$, then we have $$ \left\vert \sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right\vert = \left\vert s_m - s_n \right\vert < \varepsilon. $$ Conversely, if  for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that  $$\left\vert \sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right\vert \leq \varepsilon$$ if $m \geq n \geq N$, then $\{s_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore the series converges.

Note: In the converse part, we could have added a few steps to get the $<$ instead of the $\leq$, but that is not so important in this particular context. Am I right? a

Comment: Yup sounds correct

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could finish with only the first part by remarking that $\;\{s_n\}\;$ converges iff it is a Cauchy sequence iff...etc.

Comment: $$\left\vert \sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right\vert \neq \left\vert s_m - s_n \right\vert$$ because $$  \sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k  = s_m - s_n  $$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Criteria for convergent sequence (Baby Rudin Theorem 3.22)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786273/criteria-for-convergent-sequence-baby-rudin-theorem-3-22)

Comment: @amWhy but my question predates the one you've referred to. You see, my post is dated May 10, 2016, whereas the one you've pointed out dates back to May 15.

Comment: But *that* question has two answers, and the question itself, three upvotes.  Duplicate questions are not necessarily attributed to the earliest post, but rather, other factors (score, number of answers, etc.)